# Linking to Dynamically Created Page Link Anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a tab element with 4 different tabs each containing different bits of information.

What I'm attempting to do is link between the tabs within the tabs.

Upon inspection of the page I'm noticing the links seem to by dynamically created on page reload. Here's what one tab-link is like after 5 refreshes.

```
: http://example.com/#tab-4-172677862
: http://example.com/#tab-4-963556060
: http://example.com/#tab-4-1124062425
: http://example.com/#tab-4-1233139995
: http://example.com/#tab-4-550075197
```

So the link output seems to always be `#tab-4-123456789` or `#tab-4-1234567890` meaning `#tab-4-` with either `9` or `10` digits after.

I'm seeing RegExp `[0-9]` Expression that should account for all the numbers.

My base platform is PHP but I'm thinking trying to get the value using javascript (or jquery) would be my best bet..

The html in this is kind of like

```
<div class="tabs-wrapper tappable">
    <ul class="nab nav-tabs">
        <li class="tab-1">
          <a href="#tab-1-172677862" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tab-2">
          <a href="#tab-2-172677862" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tab-3">
          <a href="#tab-3-172677862" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tab-4">
          <a href="#tab-4-172677862" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tab-5">
          <a href="#tab-5-172677862" data-toggle="tab">Tab 5</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So what I've tried is something like this

```
<a id="tab-4-link">Tab 4</a>
```

along with a script at the top of my page

```
<script>
var tab1link = $("li.tab-1 > a").attr("href");;
document.getElementById("tab-1-link").setAttribute("href",tab1link);
</script>
```

but this is of course not working because `li.tab-1 > a` is not valid.

Anyone have any ideas as to how I can link to these? I feel like I'm overthinking this and over complicating it more than it needs to be.

Comment: You want to set href of anchor tag based on the parent <li> class with append the number as mentioned by you i.e. 24577326. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you mean by "link between the tabs within the tabs" But if you want a link that is anywhere on your page to be able to control which tab is active/visible, then this might help.

Give your "tabs-wrapper" element a unique id in case you have multiple sets of tabs on one page.

```
<div class="tabs-wrapper tappable" id="tabs-example1">
```

Give all your links used to switch tabs a class like "tab-link" and data attributes like which tab it should link to.

```
<a href="#" class="tab-link" data-tab="4" data-item="172677862">Tab 4</a>
```

Now you can prevent the default click action on all tab-link links and look for the tab it should link to then switch tabs as needed.

```
$(document).on('click', '.tab-link', function (evt) {
  // Prevents the page from reloading on click
  evt.preventDefault(); 
  var link = $(this);
  // optional unless you have more than one set of tabs on a page
  var group = link.closest('.tabs-wrapper').attr('id');
  // Reads the tab number attribute as an integer
  var tabNum = parseInt(link.data('tab'), 10);
  // Optionally read that other number from a different attribute of the link
  var item = link.data('item');
  // Do something using the tabNum.
  switchTab(tabNum);
});
```

Here is an example tab switch function, but it would depend on how you structure your tab links vs your tab content.

```
function switchTab(group, tabNum) {
  var tabs = $('#' + group + ' .tab');
  if(tabs.length < tabNum) {
    return;
  }
  tabs.removeClass('active').eq(tabNum - 1).addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Had to read this over like three times but I think I got it. Appreciate the effort and the comments, good stuff.